# Grammatik von „zu meiner Reisen“?

Tags: dative, declension, poetry

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Addition of “-n” to dative or accusative of “Erde”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31501)*

Was für ein Nomen ist *Reisen* im ersten Lied der „Winterreise“ (Müller-Schubert):

> [...]
>   Ich kann **zu meiner Reisen**
>   Nicht wählen mit der Zeit,
>   Muß selbst den Weg mir weisen
>   In dieser Dunkelheit
>   [...]

Es muss also weiblich sein, da das Adjektiv *meine**r*** ist. Aber ich kenne nur:

1. *Reise* (weiblich, aber ohne *n* am Ende)
2. *Reisen* (sächlich, das substantivierte Verb)

Woran scheitere ich?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bei *Reisen* handelt es sich in diesem Fall um eine alte Dativform von *Reise*. In moderner Sprache würde es also *zu meiner Reise* heißen.

In älterer Literatur sind derartige Formen nicht besonders selten, etwa gleich im ersten Vers von Schillers *Glocke*:

> Fest gemauert in der **Erden**
>   steht die Form, aus Lehm gebrannt.

In der heutigen Standardsprache hat sich für Feminina der Nullsingular vollständig durchgesetzt, in allen Kasus tritt also im Singular dieselbe Form auf. Allerdings sind noch ein paar feste Verbindungen erhalten, etwa *auf Seiten* und *von Seiten* (*von Seiten der Befürworter* = *von (der) Seite der Befürworter*) sowie *auf Erden*. In Dialekten kommen abweichende Deklinationen weiterhin vor.

---

Detaillierte Informationen zu derartigen alten Parallelformen findet man in Grammatiken zum Frühneuhochdeutschen, weil es darin genau um diese Übergangsprozesse zum Neuhochdeutschen geht. Die Singularformen einiger Feminina auf *-(e)n* werden etwa bei Reichmann/Wegera (Hrsg.), *Frühneuhochdeutsche Grammatik*, Tübingen 1993, in § M 18 behandelt (S. 177 f.), wo für noch mehr Einzelheiten verwiesen wird auf Nerius, *Untersuchungen zur Herausbildung einer nationalen Norm der deutschen Literatursprache im 18. Jahrhundert*, Halle 1967, S. 181 ff., und auf die große *Grammatik des Frühneuhochdeutschen*, Band 3 (*Flexion der Substantive*, Heidelberg 1987), S. 147.

Comment: Vergleiche auch das häufig gehörte, weil regional beliebte: "Zu Lübeck auf der Brücken" und "auf der Wiesen"

Comment: Mein Leben lang habe ich  denkfaul angenommen, "von Seiten" sei ein Plural, obwohl das inhaltlich unsinnig wäre... Dankeschön!

Answer (score 4):

Ich vermute keine besondere Grammatik dahinter – was nicht heißt, dass es nicht von Wissenderen derart erklärbar ist –, sondern einfach nur künstlerische Freiheit des Reimes wegen. Der Blick über die folgenden Beispiele soll kurz ein paar Varianten aufzeigen, in denen bestimmte Reime erst durch das "zurechtbiegen" bestimmter Worte möglich wurden.

---

Beispiel 1: aus [Erich Mühsams *Der Revoluzzer*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Revoluzzer)

> (...)
>      Doch die Revoluzzer **schritten**
>      Mitten in der Straßen **Mitten**,
>      Wo er ***sonsten*** *unverdrutzt*
>      Alle Gaslaternen *putzt*.
>      (...)

Allein in dieser einen Strophe des Gedichtes kommt schon sehr viel zusammen.

Zum einen ist es ein ähnlicher Vorfall, wie im Beispielgedicht des Fragestellers, indem auf **schritten Mitten** gereimt wird. Dies kann freilich dem alten Dativ zugeordnet werden, wie es von chirlu beschrieben ist, das kann aber auch einzig des Reimes wegen derart angebracht worden sein.

Zum anderen kommt eine alte Version von unverdrossen in Form des *unverdrutzt* dazu, die meiner Meinung nach sowohl des interessanten Wohlklangs des Wortes selbst dort steht als auch erneut dem Reim auf *putzt* dienen soll. Hierbei bin ich mir aber deutlich unsicherer.

On top of that gibt es, damit der Vers in das gewünschte Versmaß passt, eine gekürzte Version von "ansonsten", welches in seiner Gänze nicht gut klingen und auch nicht passen würde. ***Sonsten*** passt aber sehr gut an diesen Platz, folglich wurde es gewählt.

---

Beispiel 2: [Erich Mühsam, *Es stand ein Mann am Siegestor*](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/erich-m-4656/6)

> Es stand ein Mann am Siegestor,
>      der an ein Weib sein Herz verlor.
>      Schaut sich nach ihr die Augen aus,
>      in Händen einen Blumenstrauß.
>      Zwar ist dies nichts **Besunderes**.
>      Ich aber – ich **bewunder es**.

Hier soll **bewunder es** gereimt werden, was selbst schon eigentlich eher ein "bewunder**e** es" hätte sein müssen, das mit Bes**o**nderes nicht funktioniert. Deshalb wurde in diesem Falle der Vokal gegen einen sehr ähnlich klingenden, das O, getauscht.

---

Beispiel 3: aus [Wilhelm Buschs *Die Selbstkritik hat viel für sich ...*](http://www.wilhelm-busch-seiten.de/gedichte/kritik04.html)

> (...)
>      Auch schnapp' ich drittens **diesen Bissen**
>      Vorweg den andern **Kritiküssen**;
>      (...)

**Kritiküssen** ist ein falscher Plural von *Kritiker*, welches keinen expliziten Plural besitzt. Ohne diese stilistische Änderung ist der Reim auf **diesen Bissen** aber nicht möglich, also wurde ein reimsicherer Plural eingefügt.

Zudem würde ich hier Wilhelm Busch mit einem Augenzwinkern im Hinblick auf seine eigenen Kritiker andichten wollen, durch geschickte Verballhornung ihrer Berufsbezeichnung ihnen einen kleinen Gruß in Form eines schelmischen Kusses zukommen zu lassen.

---

Aus eigener Erfahrung beim Gedichteschreiben bin ich nicht der Überzeugung, dass hinter jedem Wort und hinter jeder Wortform irgendein großer Gedanke stehen muss, was mitnichten heißen soll, dass das irgendwie auszuschließen ist. Oftmals hat man aber einen Reim im Kopf, der irgendwie nicht will, und dann fällt einem ein Wort ein, welches vielleicht mit leichtem Verformen doch irgendwie in den Reim hineinpasst, und dann nimmt man das.